# Easyui - Two treegrid with different style in one page

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-easyui

I want to insert two treegrids in a single page but with different styles.
For example I would like in treegrid1 the indentation is only 5px and that the contents of a cell have the style white-space = nowrap while in treegrid2 the indentation is 20px and the style white-space = normal.

How can I achieve this since I have to apply the same "easyui-treegrid" class to both treegrids?
Class that moreover I have not found in any Easyui .css or .js file